# when using vue-router all things goes well but there always has error when I click the nav items?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoQuI.png)

when i click nav items there has an error, but the application goes well!

````
            <a @click="$router.push({ name:'my' ,params:{username:'hello'}})">my music</a>
            <a @click="$router.push({ name:'part' ,query:{name:'xx'}})">friend</a>```
````

Comment: somewhere in your code you're doing `xxx.match` (xxx could be anything) ... that's where the error comes from - hard to tell where, since that looks like an error from minified code - perhaps you should check in your dev environment where the line numbers for errors are likely to be more helpful

Comment: Dear friend, somewhere on the side of the Ecma script code, you set a value or a variable equal to a null, and because you encounter this error as the initial value is equal to the defined null.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.